# C++ Overloading the + operator results in error

Tags: c++

I have tried to overload the "+" operator for my class:

```
Vector operator+( const Vector& a, const Vector& b );
```

However,it tells me:

```
vector.h(12): error C2804: binary 'operator +' has too many parameters
```

I really don't get it. Please help me

Comment: Is your operator a member function of a class? If yes, add, please, the class declaration to the question.

Answer (score 10):

If you define the operator in the class, it should only receive 1 argument.

```
class Vector {
  ...
  Vector operator+ (const Vector& other) const {
    Vector res = *this;
    res += other;
    return res;
  }
  ...
};
```

The 2 argument version is used if you define it outside of the class definition.

```
class Vector {
 ...
};

Vector operator+ (const Vector& first, const Vector& second) {
  Vector res = first;
  res += second;
  return res;
}
```

Comment: For the second case, if instead of manually copying the first argument you use pass-by-value you provide the compiler a chance of optimizing away the copy if the first argument is a temporary. In `Vector operator+(Vector first, Vector const &second); Vector foo(); ... a = foo() + b;` the compiler knows that the result of the `foo()` call is a temporary bound for destruction, so it can arrange the code so that it is built in place of the first argument to the `operator+` and elide the copy. With your proposed signature the compiler cannot avoid copying the object.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have declared this as member method of class `Vector`. In that case it should take only one parameter as the object on which this operator is called is implictly available through `this` pointer. Alternalitevly, you can declare the function as a `friend` of class `Vector` and take two parameters to it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are placing the code inside the class, if that is the case, you only need to give 1 parameter (the other object), because by default the `this` object is on the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Vector on the left of the operator and the one on the right are *not* the first and second arguments. The one before the `+` is actually `this`, which is automatically supplied as a `Vector *`. You only need one argument, and that's for the Vector to the right of the `+` operator.

This would be correct:

```
Vector operator+( const Vector& b );
```

You can access the left Vector by:

```
(* this)
```

... and the right Vector by:

```
b
```

Answer (score 0):

When overloading + operator you can only have one parameter.
The other parameter is "this"

Answer (score 0):

Follow *KennyTM*, or else make your function as a `friend`..

like

`friend Vector operator+( const Vector& a, const Vector& b );`

An example can be found [here](http://learning-computer-programming.blogspot.com/2007/08/operator-overloading-using-friend.html)..

Answer (score 0):

The concrete error has been answered in a few answers already. Single parameter for the member method, two parameters for the free function version. But no hint into what path you should follow: should you remove the first parameter or else make it a free function?

The common idiom is that if you provide `operator+` you might also want to provide `operator+=`, and if you are providing both, you can implement the first in terms of the latter. Implement `operator+=` as a member function (with full access to all the state) and `operator+` as a free function that only needs to use the public `operator+=`:

```
class MyClass {
public:
   MyClass& operator+=( MyClass const & rhs );
};
MyClass operator+( MyClass lhs, MyClass const & rhs ) {
   return lhs+=rhs;
}
```

This way you have a single implementation for the operation, and you can provide both interfaces (`a + b` or `a += b`) so your interface is richer at almost no cost.

Comment: What reason is there to create a free function? Wouldn't it usually be better OO to declare `operator+` as a class method also?

Comment: @sje397: The free function operator is symmetric with respect to the data types, while the member method cannot be. Consider a type `T` that can be implicitly converted from type `T2`, and two objects `t` and `t2` from those types. If `T` has a member method `operator+`, then `t + t2` is well formed and will call that operator, but `t2 + t` will be a compile time error. With the free function implementation, both operations are allowed and have the exact same meaning --which is something one would assume from addition...

Comment: The compiler is not allowed to convert `t2` to `T` before calling a member method of `T`, but it is allowed to perform that conversion so to match the arguments of a function/method, as in `t + t2`.

Comment: @sje397 It depends. Clean code implies short class definitions trying to follow the Single Responsibility Principle (One class should do few things, but do them well). If adding the definitions of algebraic operators to the class vector polutes the class definition because it makes it too long... then you should declare it as a non member function.

Comment: @sje397 cf Chap 44. "Prefer writing nonmember nonfriend
functions" in Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ In-Depths Series - C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, And Best Practices by Herb and Stutter

Comment: The whole thing of having everything as a member method being more OO is arguable at the very least. But the discussion would be much longer than what can be handled in comments... but it is quite well handed in [What's in a class?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm) by Herb Sutter